# Vmasuながらじゃなくて - Why is じゃなくて used with ながら？

Tags: particles

> **泣きながらじゃなくて、こんな風に言ってごらん**

"*Say it like this, don't say it while crying*"

- I seem to understand how it works I think. I think I got confused since the Vmasuながら verb is the secondary action in the sentence. Please correct me if I'm wrong though.

My try

> そのアプリは勉強しながらじゃなくて、暇な時にするんだ

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly you're confused about? Your translation of that first sentence looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @Shurim I think the question is about whether the OP's attempt at creating an example sentence of his own from the template makes sense.

Comment: Probably the title and the actual question is not really matching. I post an answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

じゃなくて here is simply *not*. It can be replaced by ではなく(て).

Your example is fine, but アプリをする may not be idiomatic. A safe verb would be 使う, or if the app is game-ish, then やる would work as well.